# Why are these circuits not producing the same output?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, quantum-fourier-transform, cirq, quirk

[image]

[image]

I am simulating the phase shift algorithm on the Quirk platform. Even when the endian-ness of the built-in inverse QFT gate is corrected for, the circuits still output different results. Shouldn't the output be identical?

The bottom circuit seems to be producing the output I would expect from the phase estimation algorithm, I'm not sure what is going on with the top circuit.

I am using Quirk to ensure I am implementing the order finding algorithm correctly, so this result is kind of worrying, since I trust the built in inverse QFT over the one that I made, however, mathematically, I am fairly certain that my circuit is producing the right values.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put an extra SWAP-gate after the QFT, see [this](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:[[%22H%22,%22H%22,1,%22H%22,%22H%22],[1,1,%22X%22,1,1,%22X%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22Z%22],[1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22Z%22],[1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22Z%22],[%22QFT%E2%80%A02%22],[1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22Z%22],[1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22Z%22],[1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22Z%22],[1,1,1,%22Swap%22,%22Swap%22],[1,1,1,1,%22H%22],[1,1,1,%22Z%5E-%C2%BD%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,1,1,%22H%22],[1,1,1,%22Swap%22,%22Swap%22]]%7D) circuit.

Furthermore, the two controlled-Z gates on the same qubit are not necessary. This can reduce the circuit further to [this](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:[[%22H%22,%22H%22,%22X%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22X%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22Z%22],[1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22Z%22],[%22QFT%E2%80%A02%22,1,1,%22Swap%22,%22Swap%22],[1,1,1,1,%22H%22],[1,1,1,%22Z%5E-%C2%BD%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,1,1,%22H%22],[1,1,1,%22Swap%22,%22Swap%22]]%7D).